# Find which line a variable was defined on after importing file

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I can use the `ast` module in Python to look for `ast.Assign` nodes or `FunctionDef` nodes and look for the name of the variable being assigned to. But my issue is code like this

```py
try:
    from some_third_party_library import my_func
except ImportError:
    def my_func():
        return 'this is a fallback'
```

which may cause `my_func` to be defined in two places and you basically can't know without running the code. Is there a way for me to import this code file and then find which line `my_func` was defined on after running it?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know what file it was defined in:

```
from module1 import my_func

print(my_func.__globals__['__file__'])
```

If for example, this is the content of `module1.py`:

```
try:
    from module2 import my_func
except ImportError:
    def my_func():
        return 'this is a fallback'
```

And this is `module2.py`:

```
not_my_func = 'something else'
```

If you need the line number, this is a way to get it:

```
import inspect
from module1 import my_func

print(my_func.__globals__['__file__'])
print(inspect.findsource(my_func)[1]+1)
```

Example output:

```
C:\Python\project\module1.py
4
```

Depending on what version of Python you're using, and how much speed matters, since the above needs `inspect` anyway, this is a nice solution as well:

```
import inspect
from module1 import my_func

print(inspect.getsourcefile(my_func))
print(inspect.getsourcelines(my_func)[1])
```

Example output:

```
C:\Python\project\module1.py
4
```